# How to enables cors in lambda while using serverless framework and apiGateway

Tags: node.js, rest, cors, aws-serverless

I am using rest api which is built on nodejs with jwt token which send token as cookie it work perfectly fine in postman I am able login but when i use same api in nextjs it doesn't send cookie and also provide error telling that yours cors is not enable. So, please help to get out there. Here are my serverless.yml

```
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs14.x
  memorySize: 3008
  stage: dev
  timeout: 15
  region: ap-south-1
  cors:
    origins:
      - 'http://localhost:3000'
      - 'https://www.w3schools.com'
      - 'https://frontend-fms-vercel.vercel.app'
      - 'https://codepen.io'
    headers:
      - Content-Type
      - Authorization
    allowCredentials: true
  apiGateway:
    binaryMediaTypes:
      - '*/*'


functions:
  app:
    handler: src/app.handler
    events:
      - http: ANY /{proxy+}
      - http: ANY /
```

Somebody help me out

Answer (score 0):

By default, serverless uses the [proxy integration](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/apigateway#example-lambda-proxy-event-default):

> The Framework uses the lambda-proxy method (i.e., everything is passed into your Lambda) by default unless another method is supplied by the user

This means that your lambda is in charge of the HTTP. You need to generate appropriate CORS headers in the lambda code.